# unable to connect to remote mysql server from client website

Tags: php, mysql

website A: hosted on some free web host.

website B: my server

I want to connect from website B-(client) to mysql server of website A-(my server).

I've granted remote permission on mysql user with %.

But connection doesn't work. I've tried to run php script (mysql_connect) on different free web hosts.

- 000webhost.com : Can't connect to MySQL server on 'My SERVER IP' (4)
- biz.nf : Lost connection to MySQL server during query

same script different mysql errors.

this php script run smoothly on my online SERVER, and also on localhost setup (connecting remotely to SERVER).

Is something else I've to configure on my SERVER?

I know that free web hosts doesn't allow remote mysql connection but in my situation I'm trying to connect with my own mysql server.

Does "remote mysql access" means both in and out connetion?
I've search a lot, something to do with ip-binding or port? I dont know where is actual problem?

Kindly help me out.

Comment: Perhaps the server is firewalled? Make sure that the MySQL port (default: 3306) is open to the IP address of website A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your remote website's firewall allow external connections to the MySQL Port 3306?

Find this out to make sure you aren't spinning your tires

Comment: It is generally only allowing access to localhost connections. So check with your provider and make sure.

Comment: Yes,i do agree this,since i just solved this problem few months ago,what i did is use  'iptable' command(my server is linux pc) to open port 3306 for remote client pc.

Comment: Go ahead and use iptables to open that port. Don't forget to run iptables-save and /sbin/service iptables restart to reload the new rules.

Comment: thankyou guys, my server is also linux based but I dont know much about linux, I've to ask my server admin to do that. @Lake can you write the command you used?

Comment: Great.. thankyou so much guys .. it worked :D .. I use this. "iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT"

Answer (score 2):

Tell mysql that it should listen on a fixed IP address, not 127.0.0.1 or localhost.

open file /etc/mysql/my.cnf (or /etc/my.cnf):

**before**

```
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 127.0.0.1
```

**after**

```
# INSERT YOUR IP Address here
bind-address        = 192.168.45.1 
#bind-address=127.0.0.1
```

Then restart your mysql server. HTH